# Putting new line feed in the text for an email php

Tags: php

I am using the following code

```
$message = $mess0 . "</br>" . $mess1 . "</br>" . $mess2 . "</br>" .  $mes1 . "</br></br>" . $mes2 . "</br>" . $mes23 . "</br></br>" . $mes3  . "</br></br>" .  $mes4 . "</br>" . $mes5 . "</br>" . $mes6 . "</br>" . $mes7 . "</br>" .  $mes8 . "</br>" .  $mes9 .  "</br></br>" . $mes10 ;

$message = "<html><body><p>".$message."</p></body></html>"; 

$this->Mail($storeEmail, $subject, $message);

    function Mail($to, $subject, $message) 
    {
        $headers  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
        $headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";
        $headers .= 'From: The Vow Engagement Ring Finder <thevow.engagement@gmail.com>' . "\r\n";

        // Mail it
        if(!mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers)) {
            throw new Exception('There was a problem trying to send an email.');
        }
    }
```

The problem is all is i get is one paragraph. I have added `<br>`s but its like they don't work. The mail I get is simple paragraph without any new line feeds.

Comment: Use `<br>`, _not_ `</br>`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mistake in `<br />` tags

```
$message = $mess0 . "</br>" . $mess1...
                     ^^^^^^
```

Replace all `</br>` with `<br />`

Answer (score 0):

It will not work. You have to use \r\n for line breaks. Also try `<br />`.

Comment: $mess0 = "Name of customer: " . $cusName . "\r\n";  This dont work either i have tried already